# Why is Minecraft asking for 3 questions instead of 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I used to log into Minecraft to change my skin it would only ask 1 security question or no question at all.  When I try to change the skin now it asks 3 questions that I don't know all the answers to.  I'm not allowed to change the questions, so how do I get it back to one or no questions?

Comment: Sounds like a question for minecraft support.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you need to answer the security questions when logging in from a new computer. See this page for more details. https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/797301

> Q: When would I need to answer security questions?
>   A: When you are logging into your Mojang account from a new computer. This feature is also planned for integration with Mojang games, sometime in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont have a computer you've signed in from before (Trusted PC)

Follow this link 
https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new

Contact them regarding this issue from which they will help you to the best of their ability, using receipts, bank accounts ect..

Please make sure you have a parent or guardian present while proceeding with this if you are unsure.